# Android, Java : Unable to parse Time String in format 4:07 PM or 4:07 AM if Locale is es(Spanish)

Tags: java, android, date, time, simpledateformat

I am unable to guess what is the miss in parsing AM/PM time in English to Spanish AM/PM time.

After going through internet I got different views but non of them is working.

Code:-

```
Locale locale = null;
String[] languageCountryArr = null;
String language = null;
String timeString = "04:17 AM";    
//  SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");

String localeString = Locale.getDefault().toString();

if (localeString.contains("es_")){
     language = "es";
}
else {
     language = "en";
}

locale = new Locale(language);    
simpleDateFormatForTime = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a", locale);    
  try {    
        currentDateTime = simpleDateFormatForTime.parse(currentTimeString);     
        selectedDateTime = simpleDateFormatForTime.parse(selectedTimeString);     
    } catch (ParseException e) {    
        e.printStackTrace();    
    }
```

In android :- If device language is English(United States) its working fine but when device language is Spanish its throwing below Exception

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "04:17 AM" (at offset 6)
```

Please explain where is the problem in this code?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Just asking maybe I'm lack of knowledge but why "es_"? Doesn't should be "es"? Or you could use "es", "ES" which is for local and country.

Answer (score 2):

Simply try:

```
simpleDateFormatForTime = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
```

Point is: why do you want to create a formatter when you know that you will be parsing a Date that doesn't work "in Spanish"?

In other words: you know the format you intend to parse; so why do you make things more complicated by also adding that "es" locale when creating the formatter?!

Comment: Maybe "es_" is causing the problem o.O?

Comment: @Yupi Maybe. But what would happen if "es" doesn't match? Then he creates an "English" locale in the first place. If it at all, I assume that an English locale has even less problems with parsing AM / PM time than a Spanish one.

Answer (score 2):

When you always use the device locale i.e. system locale then the objection of @GhostCat should be considered. Otherwise, the line

```
if (localeString.contains("es_")) {
```

is wrong. Consider for example if a locale only contains the language and nothing else:

```
System.out.println(new Locale("es").toString()); // es
```

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

(a) Cannot reproduce your exception problem.

(b) Avoid legacy date-time classes.

Your input parses correctly with Spanish `Locale` using modern java.time classes.

```
LocalTime.parse( 
    "05:18 AM" ,
    DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedTime( FormatStyle.SHORT )
                     .withLocale( new Locale("es_ES") )
).toString()
```

> 05:18

## No problem

While I do *not* recommend using these legacy date-time classes, I did give it a shot for this Question…

I cannot reproduce your problem, using simpler version of your code with a locale of Spanish language. Also works as well with a locale of English in the United States. Granted, I did not run this in Android, I ran in the Oracle Java implementation, Java 8 Update 121, on macOS El Capitan.

```
String input = "04:17 AM";
Locale locale = new Locale ( "es" );  //Locale.US;
SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat ( "hh:mm a" , locale );

Date date = null;
try {
    date = f.parse ( input );
} catch ( ParseException e ) {
    e.printStackTrace ();
}

System.out.println ( "date.toString(): " + date );
```

> date.toString(): Thu Jan 01 04:17:00 PST 1970

See this code with legacy date-time classes [running live in IdeOne.com](http://ideone.com/s03kFF).

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

You are using troublesome old date-time classes, now legacy, supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. Much of java.time is back-ported to Java 6, Java 7, and Android (see below).

## `LocalDate`

You are trying to trade a time-of-day value into a date+time object. Instead use [`LocalTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html), designed expressly of a time-of-day without any date and without any time zone.

## ISO 8601

If at all possible, use an alternate format for your time strings. The ISO 8601 standard defines sensible practical text formats for date-time values. Rather than using a 12-hour clock with `AM` or `PM`, use the standard 24-hour clock with hours 0-23. So use `05:18` instead of `05:18 AM`, and use `17:18` instead of `05:18 PM`.

Using the ISO 8601 formats are easy, as the java.time classes uses those formats by default when parsing/generating strings.

## `DateTimeFormatter`

The [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) class defines a parsing pattern to match your input strings. You can specify the formatting pattern, or let the class automatically localize for you.

```
String input = "05:18 AM" ;

Locale l = Locale.US ;
DateTimeFormatter fTimeUS = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedTime( FormatStyle.SHORT ).withLocale( l );
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.parse( input , fTimeUS );
```

> input: 05:18 AM
>
> lt.toString(): 05:18

The same input can be parsed as Spanish as well as English, which seems to be the main point of your Question. Apparently `AM` & `PM` are used the same way in both languages.

```
DateTimeFormatter fTimeSpanishSpain = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedTime( FormatStyle.SHORT ).withLocale( new Locale("es_ES") );
LocalTime lt2 = LocalTime.parse( input ,  fTimeSpanishSpain  );
```

I do not understand why you would look for a [`Locale`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) involving Spanish and then create a Spanish-only `Locale` from that. I refer that block of code with looking for "es_". Makes no sense. Please edit your Question to explain your concern or purpose.

If you need to generate a String representing the time-of-day value but localized for the user, you should ask the user for their preferred `Locale` if vital. If not vital, the rely on the JVM’s [current default locale](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#getDefault--). But do so explicitly to make your intention clear to other programmers. If the `Locale` is omitted, the implicit use of the default creates ambiguity as to whether you so intended or if you, like so many programmers, failed to consider the issue.

```
Locale localeSpanishSpain = new Locale("es_ES") ;
DateTimeFormatter fTimeSpanishSpain = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedTime( FormatStyle.SHORT ).withLocale( localeSpanishSpain );
String output = lt.format( fTimeSpanishSpain );
```

## Live code

See this [code run live in IdeOne.com](http://ideone.com/E5XJny).

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: No one has explained the reason of the exception which I asked and I lost my earned reputation also.  Could any one please explain reason of below exception.

Comment: @VikashKumarTiwari (a) Added a section near the top of my Answer showing that a simpler version of **your code works just fine** parsing your input string with Spanish locale using the legacy date-time classes. See that code [running live in IdeOne.com](http://ideone.com/s03kFF). (b) BTW, those legacy classes *really* are bad; you should drop them ASAP and move on to java.time. (c) Tip: Simplify your code as much as possible when posting: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

I also know that I can overcome this problem by using new features provided in Java 8. Simply I also can go through the oracle Java documentation and read that one. I want to face problems and find out their solution and for that reason we join StakOverFlow as for as I know. No one has explained the reason of the exception which I asked and I lost my 5 earned reputation.  Could any one please explain reason of below exception.

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "04:17 AM" (at offset 6)
```

Comment: (a) Not a proper Answer. I suggest deleting before accumulating down-votes. You can make comments on Answers, make comments on your Question, or revise your Question (if the overall meaning remains the same). (b) You may have received down-votes (not from me) for a poorly written Question that is unclear and lacks the full detail needed for a proper recreation of the problem. For example, the values of `localeString`, `currentTimeString`, nor `selectedTimeString`. Compare your confusing example code to my straightforward version seen in [my Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41906555/642706).